# How to use different menu for mobile - Shopify (mmenu)

Tags: javascript, shopify, mmenu

I started to work on Shopify store. The previous developer used mmenu to create the mobile menu.

I want to use different menus for mobile and desktop, the question is, how can I control which menu is shown by mmenu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you are cloning the menu (Because the plugin makes lot of changes to the html) with the following option:

```
$("#my-menu").mmenu({
   // options
}, {
   // configuration
   clone: true
});
```

Then you need to add the css based on the id (prepend mm-) in order to display the original or the clone.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #my-menu {
      display: none !important;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
   #mm-my-menu{
      display: none !important;
   }
}
```

[Here's the actual documentation](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/tips-and-tricks.html) for that